# Selecting element to center something using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why did I have to set `.footer-background` to `display: flex` to center the `.copyright-text`? Why wouldn't setting `display: flex` to `.footer` work?

```css
.footer-background {
  background-color: #00008B;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.copyright-text {
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
max-width: 1200px;
padding: 0 48px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-background">
  <footer class="container footer">
    <p class="copyright-text">Copyright &copy; The Odin Project 2021</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Using the code you've provided, adding flex to `.footer` results in the behaviour you'd expect. Are you missing some code here from your actual implementation that's preventing reproduction of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the `display: flex;` on footer, when you will set the flex on `.footer-background`, flexibility will apply on footer element

Because when you apply flex on any element, its direct children will be effect, it doesn't matter that what is the content inside the children element

Answer (score 0):

If you have to set .footer-background to `display: flex` or setting .footer work to `display: flex`. in both cases the text in .copyright-text will be centered.

```html
<div class="footer-background">
      <footer class="container footer">
        <p class="copyright-text">Copyright &copy; The Odin Project 2021</p>
      </footer>
</div>
```

But instead of assigning

```css
.footer {
  height: 50px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.copyright-text {
  color: #f9faf8;
}
```

you can simply assign the property of `text-align:center;` and it will centralize the text.

```css
.footer {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.copyright-text {
  color: #f9faf8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by setting display:flex on the footer

```css
.footer {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.copyright-text {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <footer class="footer">
    <p class="copyright-text">Copyright &copy; The Odin Project 2021</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```